# How to select multiple files using shift and left mouse button?

Tags: windows-explorer

How would I select multiple files after using <kbd>shift</kbd> and left mouse button.

I have 100 files selected and needed to skip 2 files and multi select 300 more. Is this possible without having to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and individually selecting the 300 addition files?

Answer (score 2):

Select all files (using <kbd>shift</kbd>+click or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), then use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click to unselect the two files you do not want selected.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail. I have about 2000 files I need to go through and probably have about 300 or so that are scattered that I do not need selected. I was just wondering if there was a way to multi select and skip a few then multi select then skip a few and so on.

Comment: @user1249220 There is no way to do that. Unless the files you want to unselect are in groups so large that you can't click on all of them you're best off using the method in my answer. If that's not sufficient for you, see if there's a more useful way to sort the files. If you need more control than *that*, then you might want to just write a quick program to move all the files you want to a different folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do what you want.

How are the 'exclusions' defined? Maybe there is an attribute you can sort for, like image width or size or whatever. Files in Windows have several dozen attributes that you can add in the explorer display (although it might get really slow), and then sort by.